# Deploy Software with Ansible on a Platform without install privileges

Tags: linux, ansible, elasticsearch

A while ago I have installed [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/) on a cluster of 8 machines , on which I do not have install privileges , therefore I manually downloaded the binaries on each machine and created aliases to run the services .
Now I have a new platform with way more nodes, so I wanted to use [Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#becoming-an-unprivileged-user). I followed the instructions provided in this [repository](https://github.com/elastic/ansible-elasticsearch).  It seems that all playbooks I have found needs install permissions (sudo yum install in this case).

My question is : Is it possible to install the binaries using Ansible without having install permissions ?  Thank you.

Comment: Define "install permissions". AFAIK there is no such thing on Linux, but installing software usually requires access rights to parts of the filesystem that are R/O (or unreadable) by regular users (/usr/bin, /etc, and wherever the package manager keeps information...). If all you do is copy binaries to directories where you have write access then Ansible can still be used.   Also, which Linux flavor?

Comment: by install I mean sudo yum install , as I am using a RHEL. And, yes what I did so far is to copy the binaries using Ansible , but I thought there might be a better solution to do it.